# Debugger is not working Properly in Visual Studio Code , it says launch: program " does not exist and 2 other Problems

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am new to programming in Visual Studio Code and I have 3 Problems:

1. My Debugger is not working , it always says " launch: program " does not exist" .
   I posted pictures of my settings and Extensions.
2. How can I change my compiler and my wall settings , so that if I use the run button, it always uses specific settings ? How do I turn on all the warnings ? (example: -Wall - Wextra ... etc. )
3. How can I make an external Terminal , like in Codeblocks?  I want it to do the same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ9bg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l31VW.png)

Comment: You have not added the pictures, can you please add.

Comment: Please attach the launch.json file.

Comment: Sorry i added the pictures

Comment: 1. The value of the key "program" looks little bit different, Can you please explain it ?

2. You can give this settings in the args options in launch.json.

3. Terminal is already there near the debug console,this is the terminal you are looking for, right ? What do you mean by external terminal ?

Comment: 1. that was by default , i did not change anything. 2. ah ok thx . 3. Do you know codeblocks? if i run a code there , it starts the programm in a CMD window or in the compiler window . thats what i want.